# Approximation of the radon-derivative

Tags: measure-theory, fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, reference-request

I am  looking for the following statement. 
Let $X$ be a topological space and let $\mu$, $\nu$ be Radon-Borel measures in the same measure class i.e. the the zero-sets are identical. Denote then by $f$ the Radon derivative.

We can assume a lot of regularity on $X$ i.e. it is compact, locally compact...
Also we can assume some regularity on $\mu$, $\nu$ i.e. atom-freeness the support is X...

Is then the following statement true.

For each $x$ in $X$ outside a measure zero-set and for each sequence of nested open sets $U_i$ whose intersection is only $x$ it follows that 
$f(x)=\liminf \mu(U_i)/\nu(U_i) $

Are there any further assumption for $U_i$?

Thanks

Comment: By Luzin's theorem, $f$ is continuous except for a set of arbitrarily small measure; if $f$ is continuous at $x$ then your limit equals $f(x)$. This has to be made more accurate though.

Comment: Try to search for material on Lebesgue points. If $\nu$ is the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R^n$, then almost every point is a Lebesgue point and so has your property.

Comment: @Yulia: By Luzin's theorem, *the restriction* of $f$ to some set $E$ of almost full measure is continuous or, if you prefer, $f$ equals to some other continuous function $g$ outside a set of small measure. This is very different from the continuity of $f$ itself. The theorem on Lebesgue points also requires very particular shapes of $U_i$ to employ covering lemmas. @Klaus The desired property is currently stated so sloppily that it doesn't hold even at points of continuity: take $X=\mathbb R$, $x=0$, and $U_i=(-1/i,1/i)\cup (i,+\infty)$.

Comment: @yulia: many thank's, embarassingly I did not know the notion of Lebesgue points. As X is also metric and one measure is the Hausdorff measure there might be some theorem that almost every point is lebesgue.
@fedja: Many thank's for correcting me, my question is missleading. Actually, I am looking for a criterion for the shape of $U_i$.   

Comment: @fedja: thank you, I forgot much of it since using.
@Klaus: I remember reading a good review close to this topic: A. Bruckner, “Differentiation of integrals,” Amer. Math. Monthly 78 (9, part II) (1971).

Answer (score 1):

Here some references that show that (surprisingly!) the result you stated is wrong  if $\liminf$ is replaced by $\limsup$ and $X=\mathbb{R}^2$.

More precisely, if $\nu$ is the Lebesgue measure on the unit square $[0,1]^2$, there exists an integrable function $0\leq f\in L^1(\nu)$ such that the measure $\mu$ given by $\mu(A):=\int_A f d\nu$ satisfies the following property:

for $\nu$ a.e. $x$ there exist open rectangles $A_n=(a_n,b_n)\times (c_n, d_n)$ such that $x\in A_n$, $b_n-a_n\to 0$, $d_n-c_n\to 0$ and $\limsup \frac{\mu(A_n)}{\nu(A_n)}=\infty$. Notice that by replacing $A_n$ with a subsequence you can assume without loss of generality that the $A_n$ are nested.

This example is taken from  Theorem 7.2.10 of the book `Stopping Times and Directed Processes' by Edgar and Sucheston. You can also find it (although it is much less readable) in 1.5.1. Proposition in the book`Derivation and Martingales' by Hayes and Pauc. In these books you will also find a lot of info on additional conditions under which the conclusion you stated holds (with $\lim$, not just $\liminf$); for example, if you use open rectangles and $\nu,\mu$ are as above, then the result holds if $f$ satisfies a stronger integrability property, namely $f\log^+(f)\in L^1$

Comment: To clarify: what makes the counterexample above possible is that the sides of the rectangles collapse at different rates. Indeed, if there exist constants $a,b$ such that $0<a\leq \frac{b_n-a_n}{d_n-c_n}\leq b<\infty$ for all $n$ then for $\mu$ a.e. $x$ there exists $ \lim_n \frac{\mu(A_n)}{\nu(A_n)}$ and equals $f(x)$ (a more general statement is shown in theorem 7.10 in the book `Real and complex analysis' by Rudin for the case where $\nu$ is the Lebesgue measure).